# When clutch is pulled down my KTM 690 R in first gear still moves forward

Tags: transmission, ktm

just changed the primary wheel drive of my KTM 690 R model 2011. Now when I put the first gear and pull down the clutch bar the bike moves forward. If anyone can help I would appreciate. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the clutch control needs adjusting so that it fully disengages.

When released, there should be just a very small amount of free play before actuation begins.

- If there is too much free play, the clutch may not disengage properly.
- If there isn't any free play, the clutch might slip when under power.

I think it is hydraulically actuated on that model, so I'm not sure *how* it would be adjusted. There seems to be plenty of advice via Mr Google  and YouTube, though.